# PLACEHOLDER - Tag Cleaner

Tags: app, placeholder, tags

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

TODO

### About

An app to help removing wrong tags from questions.

For example, the tag [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) is often [misused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) for questions about programming for Android in general.

The app will allow users to browse and review those questions, and if applicable remove the wrong tag with a single tap.

#### License

MIT

#### Download

TODO

#### Platform

Android

### Contact

TODO

### Code

> What language, frameworks, and tools were used to write this?

Kotlin, Android.

> Where can we get the code?

TODO

> How can we contribute to the code?

TODO